# Deploying Virtual Stackwise Catalyst 9400

Tags: cisco-catalyst, network-core, network-access, best-practices

I am looking into deploying Virtual Stackwise on the Catalyst 9400 series switches. I wanted to know based on best practices where should the VSL links be deployed on the Sups or the modules? Is there a Cisco document which documents this?

Thank you

Comment: This link all you have found it. [link](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst9400/software/release/16-9/configuration_guide/ha/b_169_ha_9400_cg/configuring_cisco_stackwise_virtual.pdf)

A design recommendation is on page 4.

Comment: @VLearn Page2 and 5 is explanted SVL to connection. And  I think StackWise Virtual Link (SVL) is correct not VSL. According the Doc `StackWise Virtual Link (SVL) connections are established only through 10G or 40G uplink ports on the
supervisor module. You cannot establish an SVL using a 10G port on one switch and a 40G port on the
other switch.`

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation for Configuring Cisco StackWise Virtual
The SVL link needs to be connected to the sup-module.

```
StackWise Virtual Link (SVL) connections are established only through 10G or 40G uplink ports on the
supervisor module. You cannot establish an SVL using a 10G port on one switch and a 40G port on the
other switch.
```

Please refer to the following Cisco guide for details.
Although this is not a best practice, however, the following link contains the requirements.

> Configuration guide for Cat 9400 and StackWise Virtual Link ["configuring_cisco_stackwise_virtual.pdf"](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst9400/software/release/16-9/configuration_guide/ha/b_169_ha_9400_cg/configuring_cisco_stackwise_virtual.pdf).

And this is the design guide(CVD)

> The following link is CVD ["CVD-Campus-LAN-WLAN-Design-Guide-2018JAN.pdf"](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/solutions/CVD/Campus/CVD-Campus-LAN-WLAN-Design-Guide-2018JAN.pdf).

CVD is a document that describes a verified configuration. It will be possible to find Best Practice. For deploying devices to the network

This also contains information Cat9x and StackWise Virtual Link.


As I note in the comments, I do not know if the answer to stack overflow is only to allow link paste.
However, I know that finding valid information on the official Cisco site is difficult.